# Terraform in python's subprocess freezes

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, terraform, subprocess

My script in which I run AWS VMS using terraform via python subprocess has stopped working. The  process freezes at some point.

When I exec same tf command via command-line it works. I would be grateful for any idea what could be reason why terraform in subproces stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Is it hanging waiting for you to input a value? For example if it is running `terraform apply` is it waiting for you to type `yes`?

You should set the [environment variable](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/environment-variables) `TF_INPUT=false` or pass the `-input=false` argument into the `terraform` command when running Terraform in an automated environment. You should also set the `TF_IN_AUTOMATION=true` environment variable if you care about capturing the Terraform output.

Comment: Thank Mark for your response. It is not waiting for an input cause I am using `-auto-approve` flag and all envs are set. I ran same command with same variables via bash and it worked. Actually few days ago everything was working as expected and since then I won't change code nor environment. I am wondering if I could reach some limit of requests to AWS or sth, but I could not find such info.

Comment: Can you not see the Terraform output log to see what is happening during this?